# Does the input notation to this fitness function describe (represent) a Kleene star?

Tags: notation

Does the input notation to this fitness function describe (represent) a Kleene star?

---

In an optimization problem; given an input space $X$ and a fitness function $f\;:\;X\mapsto\mathbb{R}$; the goal is to find the best $x^* \in X$ such that $f(x^*)=max_{x} f(x)$

---

If so would this $f(x^*)=max_{x} f(x)$ then read: The fitness function, given 0 to many values of $x \in X$ finds the maximum value of $x$?

Comment: No, $x^*$ is an element of $X$, namely the one where $f$ attains its largest value.

Comment: @AndreasBlass How is your interpretation determined? What steps could I have taken to better understand the intent of the author of the function. Without having to find the author and ask.

In-short, is that the common interpretation?

Comment: My "interpretation" is just restating what you already quoted: "$x^*\in X$ such that $f(x^*)=\max_xf(x)$. No special knowledge about the author or his intention is needed, just a reading of what he wrote.

Comment: @AndresBlass , Understood. Post/paste your answer and ill accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Using $x^*$ to denote a particular element of some larger set $X$ is a fairly common convention.

For it to be a Kleene star, you'd need a separate $x$ for it to be a Kleene star *of*. But in $f(x*)=\max_{x}f(x)$, $x$ is a bound/dummy variable, so there is no independent $x$ to take the Kleene star of. Therefore, the author can't have meant Kleene star.